# How to show calender in clicking textbox in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

> Here is that code where i am trying to use the web control to use this in some another place in other forms but when i am going to drag it to other form it shows error please see the code and tell me where iam going to be wrong thank u.

```
    <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="calander.ascx.cs" Inherits="Facultymanagement.calander" %>


<%--<%@ Import Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" %>--%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
/*Calendar Control CSS*/
.cal_Theme1 .ajax__calendar_container   {
background-color: #DEF1F4;
border:solid 1px #77D5F7;
}

.cal_Theme1 .ajax__calendar_header  {
background-color: #ffffff;
margin-bottom: 4px;
}

.cal_Theme1 .ajax__calendar_title,
.cal_Theme1 .ajax__calendar_next,
.cal_Theme1 .ajax__calendar_prev    {
color: #004080;
padding-top: 3px;
}

.cal_Theme1 .ajax__calendar_body    {
background-color: #ffffff;
border: solid 1px #77D5F7;
}

.cal_Theme1 .ajax__calendar_dayname {
text-align:center;
font-weight:bold;
margin-bottom: 4px;
margin-top: 2px;
color: #004080;
}

.cal_Theme1 .ajax__calendar_day {
color: #004080;
text-align:center;
}

.cal_Theme1 .ajax__calendar_hover .ajax__calendar_day,
.cal_Theme1 .ajax__calendar_hover .ajax__calendar_month,
.cal_Theme1 .ajax__calendar_hover .ajax__calendar_year,
.cal_Theme1 .ajax__calendar_active  {
color: #004080;
font-weight: bold;
background-color: #DEF1F4;
}

.cal_Theme1 .ajax__calendar_today   {
font-weight:bold;
}

    .cal_Theme1 .ajax__calendar_other,
    .cal_Theme1 .ajax__calendar_hover .ajax__calendar_today,
    .cal_Theme1 .ajax__calendar_hover .ajax__calendar_title {
    color: #bbbbbb;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
     <asp:ScriptManager ID="script" runat="server">
     </asp:ScriptManager>
    <div>
    <asp:TextBox  ID="tbEndDate" runat="server" CausesValidation="true" ReadOnly="true" Width="175px" />
    <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server"  TargetControlID="tbEndDate" CssClass= " cal_Theme1" />
    </div>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Show us something `(code)` you have tried already and where you are failing.

Comment: And what is the question ?

Comment: http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/06/ajax-calendar-extender-control-example.html

Answer (score 3):

You can set Ajax calendar extender for the textbox..

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="dtpTransDate" runat="server" Width="90px"></asp:TextBox>
  <asp:CalendarExtender ID="dtpTransDate_CalendarExtender" runat="server" 
  Enabled="True" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" TargetControlID="dtpTransDate">
  </asp:CalendarExtender>
```

Comment: Please feel free to mark as answer if the answer satisfies you...

Answer (score 1):

You can fix the issue with jQuery also.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#textboxid").datepicker();
 });
</script>

<asp:TextBox ID="textboxid" runat="server" Width="100px"></asp:TextBox>
```

If the control is in a child page of a master page
then use `ClientIDMode`

```
<asp:TextBox ID="textboxid" runat="server" Width="100px" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
```

Check below link for ClientIDMode

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode(v=vs.110).aspx

For jQuery calender check below link

http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/